Proof of the axiom of choice for finite sets in ZF
Let the set $A$ be finite and $\emptyset \notin A$. How can I, without using the axiom of choice, prove by mathematical induction that there exists a function $f : A \rightarrow \bigcup A$ satisfying $f(a) \in a$ for all $a \in A$?

@AlessandroCodenotti really, thank you, I fixed it)

It holds vacuously for $A = \emptyset$: then $\bigcup A = \emptyset$ and the empty function $\emptyset: \emptyset \to \emptyset$ trivially fulfills $f(a) \in A$ for all $a\in A$ -- because it is impossible to find a counterexample in an empty set.
Let $n_0 \in\mathbb{N}$ be the smallest number such that there is $A$ of cardinality $n_0$ with $\emptyset \notin A$, but no choice function $f:A \to \bigcup A$ with $f(a)\in a$ for all $a\in A$. We just saw that $n_0$ cannot be $0$.
So we have $n_0 > 0$. Let $a_0\in A$. Because $n_0$ is the smallest integer such that there is no choice function, there is a choice function $f:\big(A\setminus \{a_0\}\big)\to \bigcup\big(A\setminus\{a_0\}\big)$. Pick $x_0\in a_0$ (which is possible since $a_0\neq \emptyset$). Now set $$f' = f \cup \big\{(a_0, x_0)\big\}.$$ It is easy to verify that this is a choice function for $A$, contradicting the assumption that $A$ does not have a choice function.

Great answer, thank you so much!)

It was a pleasure - and welcome to MathOverflow!

I think it doesn't matter for your last paragraph that $n_0 > 1$, as opposed to $n_0 > 0$.  That is, you don't need to handle the $n_0 = 1$ case separately.

Thanks @LSpice - will use the shortcut you mention

You also really don’t need to phrase the proof as by contradiction. Anyways, the question itself is off topic here so it doesn’t need a perfect answer.

Horrible, horrible unecessary use of proof by contradition. Straight induction would have worked.

You guys don't seem to like contradiction. In Switzerland we have direct democracy, people can vote on stuff, loads of debates, so a contradictory lifestyle is in my DNA.

@AndrejBauer I am only an amateur mathematician - please cut me some slack :)

@DominicvanderZypen: all is well, you seem to be past the first stage :-)
